# Why are the strings EF retrieves different than those actually on the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am configuring the authentication of a RESTful Web API built with C# on .NET Core. My team is using Entity Framework to interact with our PostgreSQL database.
The user passwords we save on the database are hashed with SHA256.
When a client/user tries to authenticate on our API, we decrypt their password using our shared key, then hash it with SHA256 and compare the result with the hashed password we have on the database.
Right now I'm testing the code with a sample user and its hashed password came out (and was saved on the database) as such: ?-e>$?n**\u**000f??tw:$????**\u**0017et??|?J?k???S. Notice the two "\u". Unfortunately, it seems that Entity Framework interprets them as escapes and, when retrieving the User object (with its Password property), automatically adds another **\**, transforming **\u** into **\\u**.

In the following image, the upper half shows the hashed password as it's saved on the database, the lower one displays how Entity modifies it in the way I explained.

[image: Entity escaping strings automatically]

The password received from the request, when hashed by the code, matches the one on the database, as seen here:
[Hashed Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0JhL.png)

Trying to manipulate the string is out of discussion: it's a hashed password, so there's no actual pattern to follow and I can't really anticipate how Entity will interpret and modify **\** and escape-like characters or substrings in general.

My workaround makes use of *Regex.Unescape()*, but since [Microsoft itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=netframework-4.7.2) says it can't be 100% precise, I do not like it. 
In this code, *password* is the string I get from the request. I hash it using SHA256 and assign it to *hashedPassword*. When querying the database, I ask for a user (*Client*) whose username and password match the *username* I got from the request and the *hashedPassword*. Without *Regex.Unescape()*, the string retrieved by Entity Framework doesn't match *hashedPassword* (although it actually does on the database, as I explained).

```
else
{
    using (SHA256Managed shaHasher = new SHA256Managed())
    {
        byte[] hashResult = shaHasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));
        hashedPassword = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hashResult);
    }
}

using (MasterDataContext context = new MasterDataContext())
{
    try
    {
        user = await Task.Run<Client>(() =>
                    context.Client
                           .SingleOrDefault<Client>(
                                c => c.UserName.Equals(username)
                                    && Regex.Unescape(c.Password).Equals(hashedPassword)));
    }
}
```

This is quite bad, I just want to simply get my string out of the database exactly as it is, without Entity deliberately modifying it, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Converting arbitrary bytes to ASCII strings and comparing them is very strange.  Why not just store and compare the hashes as binary data.  Eg byte[] in your Entity?  Or _encode_ the binary data as a Base64 string?

Comment: I believe my answer to your original question stands, however with the additional info you've posted I believe you have a bit of an X/Y problem. I think your core concept of setting/getting/comparing the hashed passwords may be problematic and out of scope of this question. You may want to ask a new question breaking down exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: As a junior developer, I've just been told to write the code which does the job, so I don't really know the reasons behind this choice... I just know that we have users' passwords saved on our database as hashes, so we need to hash the ones we receive from requests, in order to coherently compare them.

Comment: I tried something different and found out that gilliduck is probably right about the visualization done by VS, so I must be doing something wrong. Probably the way the password was saved wasn't right. It's still quite confusing, but at least now I know what the problem *isn't*. So thank you, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Can you show the API endpoint implementation that receives the username and password that is then hashed? I ask because if you've messed up JSON handling on one of the sides, this could cause this.

Comment: Hi Lasse, in the end I thoroughly solved the problem thanks to gilliduck's hint. Each decoding/hashing now perfectly matches. To obtain the actually correct hash, I followed [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=netframework-4.7.2) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I don't like to post pictures as part of a question/answer, but in this case it's worth a 1000 words. Long story short, what you're seeing is just how VS displays backslashes. It escapes it in display, but doesn't actually change it. As you can see in my screenshot, I have a text file that is full of escape characters. VS is adding the additional slashes, but when I either write to console or write to a file, those additional slashes are not part of the data.

[image: SnippetShowingAllStyles]

Comment: Hello gilliduck and thanks for your time. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case, as the two strings actually do not match. I tried using Regex.Unescape(hashedPasswordFromDB) and the string changed back to its actual state as of the database. However, I don't like this solution, as [Microsoft itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=netframework-4.7.2) says .Unescape() isn't 100% precise.

Comment: @StackLloyd you may want to post some additional code then. Entity Framework does not modify/alter the content unless you do so. If your code is being edited, then there must be something sanitizing it because that's not default behavior.

Comment: I posted the involved lines of code. I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I just can't figure it out...